# JQuery Grid in struts2 - beginner

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, struts2, jqgrid, struts2-jquery

Im new to struts2 and JQuery programming. Im my application, when the loginAction is called and if the user is an Admin i direct them to the AdminLoadAction. This action loads the adminHome.jsp. What i need is for adminHome.jsp to use a JQueryGrid to display all the customers in the system. Right now my AdminLoadAction returns success (i use jdbc to connect to DB so i query my db and get a List of all the customers in the system, which works fine).

I have been trying to find good step by step kind of tutorials but havent found any. Can Some one give an idea of what change will i need to do to achieve this. So far i have downloaded and added the struts2-jquery plugin, struts2-jquery-grid plugin and the struts2-json plugin to my project.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the jquery grid example app?

Comment: @DaveNewton i have but they dont exactly have explanations..im a beginner...an abstract view of what the flow is and what needs to happen would help me relate with the an example better....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you already seen this slides?

http://www.slideshare.net/johannesgeppert1/introduction-into-struts2-jquery-grid-tags

Another good point to start is study the examples in the [Showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action) and [Showcase Grid App](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/index.action). And take a look at the Wiki Pages around the [Grid Tag](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag).

Johannes