# Update a particular record in a table using struts2 and javascript

Tags: java, javascript, struts2, jqgrid, displaytag

How can I make the particular record editable and after changing the fields update to that particular record. I have never used JavaScript so I am facing a lot of perplexion between the javascript, Struts 2 and hibernate. Following are the required material to help me out.
I want to:

1. Make the particular record editable.
2. Update that record

organizationTable.jsp

```
<display:table id="record" name="listOfOrganization" requestURI="/organization" pagesize="10">
    <display:caption>Organization Records</display:caption>
    <display:column property="id" />
    <display:column property="name" />
    <display:column property="ceo" />
    <display:column property="address" />
    <display:column property="establishedDate" />
    <display:column property="category" />
    <display:column property="url" />
    <display:column property="phoneNumbers" />
    <display:column property="fax" />
    <display:column property="status" />
    <display:column media="html">
        <form action="">
            <input type="submit" value="Update" />
        </form>
    </display:column>
</display:table>
```

Organization class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ORGANIZATION")
public class Organization {
@Id @Column(name="UID")
    private String id;
    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="CEO")
    private String ceo;
    @Column(name="ADDRESS")
    private String address;
    @Column(name="ESTABLISHED_DATE")
    private String establishedDate;
    @Column(name="CATEGORY")
    private String category;
    @Column(name="URL")
    private String url;
    @Column(name="PHONE_NUMBERS")
    private String phoneNumbers;
    @Column(name="FAX")
    private String fax;
    @Column(name="STATUS")
    private String status;
// setters & getters
}
```

Snapshot

[image]

Comment: There's a plugin that can make you life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DisplayTag`](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/changes-report.html) is quite old now, latest version is from 2008;

If you can (eg. if you are NOT adding functionalities to an existing, huge legacy project, but instead you are at the beginning and/or starting a new project right now), I suggest you to invest some time and study [`jqGrid`](http://www.trirand.com/blog/), probably [the best grid out there](http://jqueryrock.com/2014/03/jqgrid-vs-datatable.html) today.

Your specific case with examples and full code is available [in the demo page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html), under

1. <kbd>Row Editing (new)</kbd> <kbd>Basic Example</kbd>
2. <kbd>Row Editing (new)</kbd> <kbd>Custom Edit</kbd>

Note that, since you are using Struts2, and you don't know Javascript, you mihgt be interested in an easier approach, using the [GridTag](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag) from the [`Struts2-jQuery-Grid-plugin`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12358720/1654265) created by [jogep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/352721/jogep).

Take a look at [the Struts2-jqGrid Showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/index.action) to see *what* it can do, 
and at [the documentation](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag) to see *how* (easy it is) to do it.